# How to access to folders not to files in a specific folder in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Suppose i have a folder, In this folder exist some files and folders, I want to access to folders not to files. How do i do that. I know to exist this function in c++ :`FindFirstFileA` and i write following code, but this work for files.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
string s = "E:\\OpenCV\\SABT\\Old";

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(s.c_str(), &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
{
    printf("no file found");
    return -1;
}

if (ffd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{

    do
    {
        std::string fn = path + ffd.cFileName;
        printf("file %s\n", fn.c_str());

    } while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
}
```

Comment: `FindFirstFileA` is a Windows API wrapper function, not a C++ standard library function. If you choose to use the Windows API you can avoid a bunch of problems by using the basic wide character APIs, based on `wchar_t`, i.e. `FindFirstFileW` (or just define `UNICODE` and write `FindFirstFile`). The C++ standard library's functionality *will be* the almost wholesale adoption of Boost file system. It's already available with Visual C++, which it looks like you're using. Otherwise, if it's not available with your compiler, just install the latest Boost.

Comment: findfirstfile and findnextfile will work for both files and folders.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf  you're right. this function is Win API.

Comment: @Stuart thanks. Do you mean that i can't use this function to find just folders??

Comment: You just need to ignore files, as your code attempts to do. Your test of the attributes is wrong though. I needs to test if the bit flag is set using bitwise operations. An object may have multiple attributes.

Comment: But you need to move the test for being a directory inside your loop. You will be able to find countless examples of how to do this with a websearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `ffd.dwFileAttributes` the wrong way.  It is a bitmask, and a directory can have multiple attributes at a time, so you need to use the `&` bitwise AND operator instead of the `==` equality operator.

Don't forget to also check/ignore the `"."` and `".."` entries when enumerating subfolders. And call `FindClose()` when you are done enumerating.

Try something more like this instead:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
string path = "E:\\OpenCV\\SABT\\Old\\";

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA((path + "*.*").c_str(), &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
{
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
       printf("no folders found\n");
    else
       printf("error searching for folders\n");
    return -1;
}

do
{
    if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
    {
        if ((lstrcmpA(ffd.cFileName, ".") != 0) &&
            (lstrcmpA(ffd.cFileName, "..") != 0))
        {
            std::string fn = path + ffd.cFileName;
            printf("%s\n", fn.c_str());
        }
    }
}
while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd));

if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
{
    printf("error searching for folders\n");
}

FindClose(hFind);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
string s = "E:\\OpenCV\\SABT\\Old";

HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA(s.c_str(), &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
{
   printf("no file found");
   return -1;
}

do
{
   if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
   {
     std::string fn = path + ffd.cFileName;
     printf("file %s\n", fn.c_str());
   }
} while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```